# create and read test file android

Tags: java, android

For testing my parser in android project I hardcoded some file which I put in application folder in a way like this (my file is `0_0.xml`)

[image]

now I'm trying to open it with

```
File inputFile = new File(fileName);
```

but it says that the file is not found

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /0_0.xml
```

I did not work much with android but in my just `java` projects I used to put some files in root directory of a project and this code

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
```

worked fine. So how should I open or where should I put my test files to read it in android project?

Comment: usually you would put it in the assets or in the raw directory : http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html (`main/assets/` and `main/res/raw`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your file in `asset` folder (src/main/assets/)

and read file from asset folder:

```
getAssets().open(filename);
```

Comment: As I see this method `open` returns `InputStream` but I need it to be `File` because I want to use `DocumentBuilder.parse` on it.

Answer (score 0):

That filename is the fully qualified file path ON THE ANDROID DEVICE. So its looking for the file at the root of the FS. You need to copy the file to the sdcard or something and use the full path to open it.

Comment: but if I just need to test some piece of code. Am I able to do it without saving it on sdcard?